# using read() function in python gives extra characters or symbols in the next write() function

Tags: python

When i use `read_eager` or `read_very_eager` in a telnet connection , the immediate `write()` is giving an extra character. This fails the logic I have implemented.

```
login = session.read_very_eager()
print login

if login.find("Login incorrect") == 0:
    print "incorrect username or password"
else:
    print "login successful"

session.write("logout" + "\n")
```

This is a snippet of the code I have used. The last `write()` is actually writing "%logout" in the terminal. The code works fine when I comment out the `login = session.read_very_eager()` statement.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening and any possible solution that I can use?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For future questions, please format you code snippet correctly (see here :  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with what exactly you are doing here, but in my experience extra characters are usually solved by encoding correctly. you might want to give that a try.
your question is not comprehensive enough I'm not sure what you want to do but you can use `data.encode('utf8')` before it's written to the file.

Comment: Thanks mid. Actually i was able to resolve it by adding a backspace character in my write() function. Thus i was able to avoid the extra % symbol in my what i am trying to write to console. Although i do not think this is the right way, it works for the moment. Anyway i will try the encode method you have suggested.

Comment: yes that is definitely not right, and yes try encoding that should solve the issue.